# Convert String of Json object lists to list of JSON objects

Tags: java, json, type-conversion

After making a HTTP get request i'm returned with a list of JSON objects, is there any way in which I can convert this String into a list of JSON objects??

Example response:

```
[{"name":"test","description":"","dbType":"sql server"}, 
{"name":"test1","description":"","dbType":"sql server"}, 
{"name":"test2","description":"","dbType":"sql oracle"}]
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: If you are talking about getting JSON to browser client side, you could use javascript's: JSON.parse(jsonstringvar)

Comment: In Java you can use Jackson Fasterxml Api , and incase of client side as @MRsa mentioned you can use Javascripts Json.parse

Comment: @MRsa Hi thanks, but the end goal after converting the string is to extract values from the JSON objects in Java

Comment: @RahulRabhadiya Okay thanks i'll have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple json api can do what you want for e.g

```
String stringToParse  = "[{'name':'test','description':'','dbType':'sql'}, "
            + "{'name':'test1','description':'','dbType':'sql server'},"
            + "{'name':'test2','description':'','dbType':'sql oracle'}]";


JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray json = (JSONArray) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

You can also look into Jackson json api.